# How to render PDF forms for the user to fill out?

Tags: ios, pdf

I'm tasked to come up with a way to render PDF forms on iOS devices and give the user the ability to fill out these forms. Once the form is completed, the user can then push a submit button and the form will be sent to a web service.

Is this feasible? Has any of you used any 3rd party tools / libraries that would alleviate this task?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Too late but , You can use ILPDFKit - https://github.com/iwelabs/ILPDFKit

Answer (score 8):

Here's something that does the trick: https://github.com/iwelabs/ILPDFKit

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of something that renders fillable PDFs in IOS.

If you want to render a web form, that converts into a PDF with the field contents, then yes.

If so, yes there's a webservice for that - a demo is [here](http://www.pdfmyform.com/demo)

Comment: There has to be a way. I downloaded an app called PDF Max and it allows users to fill out PDFs. I found this SDK that advertises that it can be done, I'm going to try to contact them http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/index.html